# Stuck: Show that $TS$ is self-adjoint if and only if $TS = ST$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ and $S$ be self-adjoint operators on an inner product space $V$. Show that $TS$ is self-adjoint if and only if $TS = ST$.

I got the backward directions and am stuck on the forward directions. So I have $\langle TSv,w\rangle = \langle v, TSw \rangle$ because $TS$ is self-adjoint. We also know since $S,T$ are self-adjoint that $\langle TSv, w \rangle = \langle Sv, Tw \rangle = \langle v, STw \rangle = \langle v, TSw \rangle$. From here, how do I conclude that $ST = TS$? I thought I finished the proof but I realized say $v \neq v'$, then $\langle v, 0 \rangle = \langle v', 0 \rangle$ but $v \neq v'$.

Edit: Wait a second, is the proof complete?

Comment: Hint: Prove that for fixed vectors $x$ and $y$, if $\langle v,x\rangle = \langle v,y\rangle$ *for all* $v$ in $V$, then $x=y$. Conclude that $TS(w)=ST(w)$ for all vectors $w$.

Comment: $\langle v, (STw-TSw)\rangle=0$ for any $v$ implies $STw-TSw=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T\in{\scr{L}}{(V)}$ is self-adjoint iff $T^{*}=T$

where $T^{*}\in{\scr{L}}{(V)}$ defined by  $$\langle Tv, w\rangle=\langle v, T^{*} w\rangle$$

$ST$ self-adjoint.

$\implies (ST) ^{*}=ST$

$\implies T^{*} S^{*}=ST$

$\implies TS=ST$